# Android Geocoding - not running in other device

Tags: android, maps, geocoding, device

I use [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/) tutorial to search locations. But on my device this app does not work, my device is with android 4.1.2

With my emulator this app works perfect. And I tested the app with other real device with android 2.3.6 and on that device again works perfect.

How this is possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />


<permission
        android:name="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:vmSafeMode="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    >


    <activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:name="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.Languages"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


                                            <activity

                                                    android:name="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.razhod.PytCena.RazhodCena"
                                                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                                                    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                                            </activity>


                                            <activity

                                                    android:name="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.razhod.PytCena.LitriKm"
                                                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                                            </activity>


                                            <activity

                                                    android:name="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.razhod.PytCena.RazhodNa100Km"
                                                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                                                    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                                            </activity>





                                            <activity
                                                android:name="com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.razhod.PytCenaGoogleMaps.RazhodCenaGoogleMaps2"
                                                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                                                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                                            </activity>

                                            <meta-data
                                                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                                                    android:value="AIzaSyAMCbpjl8DHbfr3MJ4-51mkIobb0XI1fYE"/>



                                        </application>

                                    </manifest>
```

Log-cat errors:

```
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Service not Available
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.razhod.PytCenaGoogleMaps.RazhodCenaGoogleMaps2$GeocoderTask.doInBackground(RazhodCenaGoogleMaps2.java:204)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1.razhod.PytCenaGoogleMaps.RazhodCenaGoogleMaps2$GeocoderTask.doInBackground(RazhodCenaGoogleMaps2.java:194)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-09 16:40:29.727  22094-22268/com.mitko.razhodnagorivo1 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: does your phone is connected...correctly... and if yes...then what your getting any error....

Comment: With my device when I search for some city I get Toast - "No Location found". But when I search for some location in my emulator or on my other device with 2.3.6 everything works perfect.

Comment: can you post your androidManifest.xml...

Comment: can you tell me the when you run the app in the real device in log-cat can you see any error message...

Comment: with the emu in logcat I don't have any problems, but in my real device I get some errors in log cat. I will post them in my post page.